# How to test for undefined variable repeatedly?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a beginner project, a Rock, Paper, Scissors game. However I am having trouble with a variable, I basically made three buttons, Rock, Paper and Scissors, and when you click one of the buttons I return the variable to the function. However when I assign a global variable the value of the function, it first says undefined and then when I click it again it says Rock, papers, or scissors, I tried to do an if statement that only alerts when the variable is not null but it doesn't seem to work.

JS Code

```js
function gameFunction(choice) {
  userChoice = choice;
  return userChoice;
}

playerChoice = gameFunction();

if (playerChoice != null) {
  alert("Test");
}
```

Comment: Your `gameFunction` function expect to get 1 parameter, but when you call it you didn't send any parameter... Read your code again.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When posting code make sure you add all relevant pieces. In your snippet the declaration of the variable and the assignment statements seem to be relevant as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the variable playerChoice is undefined the first time you load the code. You need instead (if you decide to insist in global variables) to define playerChoice with a defined and valid value.

like:

```
playerChoice = "Rock"
```

This happens because javascript follows (among others) a event-oriented programming paradigm, so in the first iteration of your application, I assume it waits for the user to choose by a click event?, but what value does it have before the click event?

In short, you need to define your global variable to a known state, even if the player will change it later.

Hope it helps.